# How to remove the null values in the row of the table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My picture:

[image]

In this i am fetching data from table daybook and display in view page.

Now my problem is i don't want to display the row if the both credit and debit has "0".
I haven't to display the praveen kumar accounts to icici in that picture because it has zero value on the both the column.

This is my controller code:

```
$data['PName'] =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM accmaster ")->result_array()
```

Comment: Did you know the [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) query has a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Also in SQL null is very different from `0` and an empty string.

Comment: i know where clause

Comment: Good. Use it to match the filtering criteria you want.

Comment: I have used where condition but it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL is missing the WHERE clause, use following:

```
$data['PName'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM accmaster WHERE Debit!=0 OR Credit!=0")->result_array()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the where clause to filter out the values containing zero.

```
$data['PName'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM accmaster WHERE DEBIT > 0 OR CREDIT > 0")->result_array();
```

I hope this will do.